# Android tool and platform-tools folders disappeared

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

After update my SDK tools and platform-tools folders disappeared of my SDK

My SDK directories Tree
https://gist.github.com/LuizCarvalho/6870443
 And My Android SDK folder
[image: android sdk folder]

Comment: your question is about, why it disappeared ? or how to retrieve them ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you can download them separately from:

sdk tools: 
http://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r22.0.5-windows.zip

platform-tools: 
http://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r18.0.1-windows.zip

Comment: @JoshBjelovuk just by spying the SDK Manager while downloading the tools.

Comment: All the points in the world to you my friend... http://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r25.0.3-linux.zip

Answer (score 4):

The Platform Tools is now seperated. Open the SDK Manager and download "Android SDK Platform-tools" at the top in the Tools folder.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to Window -> SDK Manager. Re-download what you're missing.

Comment: SDK Manager is a shortchut for the "tools/android" folder, this folder is missing...

Comment: I would just re-download the SDK then.